# Blazor binding checkbox in foreach loop

Tags: c#, data-binding, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I would like to bind at runtime a checkbox in a foreach loop.

I get this error :

```
Cannot assign to 'item' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'


@foreach (var item in myPerson.Persons) {
    <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked=item.IsAlive />
}

@code{
    var myPerson = new MyPerson();
    
    public class MyPerson
    {
        public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }   

    public class Person
    {
        public bool IsAlive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: This won't compile. And it won't give the error you quoted. Write a proper [mre] and make sure it reproduces the problem before posting.

Comment: That's the point : Cannot assign to 'item' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable' I'd like assign the binding to 'item'.

Comment: This code is not 'assigning to item'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding appears to be correct, are you sure you're properly initializing the myPerson object?

Below is an example of code that works flawlessly:

```cs
<ul>
    @foreach (var person in _myPerson.Persons)
    {
        <li>@person</li>
    }
</ul>
    
@foreach (var item in _myPerson.Persons)
{
    <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@item.IsAlive" Label="@item.Name" />
}

@code {

    private readonly MyPerson _myPerson = new MyPerson()
    {
        Persons = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person("Bob"),
            new Person("Alice")
        }
    };

    public class MyPerson
    {
        public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public Person(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; }
        public bool IsAlive { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() => IsAlive ? $"{Name} is alive" : $"{Name} is dead";
    }
}
```

Comment: yours is definitly the better answer.